# How to absolutely center object when it's size is defined by % of screen size

Tags: html, css

I have divs that are sized according to screen size. On the old version of the site, I was sizing them with specific pixel sizes. I remade it so it would look good on all screen sizes, but I am having trouble with positioning them directly in the center. I am aware of the margin-left and margin-top trick, but that only works with set pixel sizes. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried the methods mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could center div by using

```
    div {
        width:50%;
        height:25%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;    
       }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1trzpz27/1/)